# Is it possible to create multiple widgets with one method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I'm creating multiple labels in one window and I'd like to use one method in the class to create them and just pass the name, text, etc to the function when I call it. In testing I am not finding a way to use a variable I give the function as the name of the widget. Is it possible to do this or would I need multiple methods? If passing a name for the widget name is not possible is there another way to use one method to create multiple widgets?

```
class framemkr(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def lblmkr(self, name, words, frame):
        self.name= Label(frame, text=words)
        self.name.grid()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using tkinter.

You can't use "name" to name the variables in the label maker as you have proposed, but you should not need to either, if you don't want to interact with the label later. You could just do it like this:

```
class framemkr(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_label(self, text, row, column, frame):
        """ Adds a label to the GUI when called.
        """
        Label(frame, text=text).grid(row=row, column=column)
```

Otherwise, if you want to interact with the label and save the variable you could save it in a dictionary:

```
class framemkr(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.labels = {}

    def add_label(self, name, text, row, column, frame):
        """ Adds a label to the GUI when called.
        """
        label = Label(frame, text=text)
        label.grid(row=row, column=column)
        self.labels[name] = label
```

You could thus access the label variable later from the dictionary.

Comment: I would need to access them later so i'd have to name the widgets. I've done the dictionary thing before but I was looking other options. If that's the only way then im fine with going that route. thanks

Comment: and yes its tkinter